# Bug em Contador em C - Problema de Sintaxe

Tags: c, debug

Galera, eu tava fazendo uns exercícios básicos de programação e me deparei com um bug do qual eu não entendi muito bem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//Program prints the odd numbers until a determined limit. 
int main()
{
    int numeric_limits;
    int count = 1;

    printf("Enter the limit number.\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numeric_limits);

    while(count <= numeric_limits)
    {
        printf(" %d\n", count);
        count+2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Este código acima fica em um loop infinito "Uns". Enquanto este aqui abaixo funciona perfeitamente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//Program prints the odd numbers until a determined limit. 
int main()
{
    int numeric_limits;
    int count = 1;

    printf("Enter the limit number.\n");
    scanf(" %d", &numeric_limits);

    while(count <= numeric_limits)
    {
        printf(" %d\n", count);
        count++;
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Eu tô programando no codeblocks... Fui testar num compilador online qualquer para ver se era problema do compilador, mas no compilador online deu loop infinito também... Alguém sabe por que isso acontece?

Comment: Pensa bem, a linguagem foi criada há 45 anos, os compiladores estão aí há décadas, milhões de pessoas fizeram projetos complicadíssimos aos montes durante todos estes anos e ninguém achou esse suposto *bug* no compilador. Quais as chances do problema não ser no seu código extremamente simples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
count+2;
```

Acho que você quis dizer isso:

```
count += 2;
```

Ou seja, você se esqueceu do `=`.

Comment: Nesse caso o count não está sendo incrementado, é só um erro de lógica...

Comment: Muito Obrigado!! Ajudou imensamente!! Será um erro que provavelmente não voltarei a cometer =D!!